# Creating an FTP server with python

Tags: python, ftp, ftp-server

I need to create an **FTP server using python**, a larger professional and secure app not just a tiny simple one, any suggestion on where can I start from ?

is there any python open-source FTP server project which I might be able to use? or any good **FTP server library**?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://pypi.org/project/pyftpdlib/

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-ftp-server/